# scroll to top using .animate if at top stop - jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-scrollable

im using .animate to scroll to the top of the page, but if the user is already at the top or very near it and they click .proj-tile they wont be able to scroll down again for 1200ms is there a way to stop the script stop when the top is reached ?

```
 $('.proj-tile').click(function()   {
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: '+0'   }, 1200);
});
```

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a condition to check the height of the scroll and call the animate accordingly,

```
$('.proj-tile').click(function()   {
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= 300) { //has scrolled considerably to animate
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: '+0'   }, 1200);
    }
});
```

Comment: DEMO >> http://jsfiddle.net/skram/KwgMj/3/ << You need to scroll at least 100 to get the animate to kick in.